# Keyboard backlight keeps turning on after uprgade to Wily on Dell V131, what can be the cause?

Tags: keyboard, dell, backlight, 15.10

I have a Dell V131 with and recently upgraded it to Ubuntu (15.10) Wily Werewolf. Now, the keyboard backlight keeps turning on. I have not seen it turn on and mostly notice when I come back to the laptop after a few minutes.

How can I find out what turns on the backlight and stop it from happening on its own?